# How to get the pass one Json object into another

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am doing Json parsing and have stuck up over here, where in a jsonobject and inside that i have another jsonobject. I am getting the label etc values but how do i parse the actionParam values that is inside.

```
{
                "label": " Day Schedule",
                "action": "schedule",
                "actionUrl": "https:\/\/www.abc.com\/api\/2\/event\/schedule.php",
                "actionParams": {
                    "id": "108501",
                    "dr": "1390107600-1390194000",
                    "track": "108625"
                }
```

thank you in advance

Comment: On the same object that you're using to parse out `label`, `action` etc, call `getJSONObject("actionParams")`. Then use the return value of that to parse the `id`, `dr` and `track` in the same way you do with the other fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the actionParams value is actually a nested `JSONObject` - as indicated by the { } bracket. You need to think of parsing JSON as unpacking a set of Russian nesting dolls. You need to

(1) Create a `JSONObject` for the intiial string that contains actionValues

```
JSONObject firstObject = new JSONObject(stringValue);
```

(2) Get the actionParams `JSONObject` from this initial object

```
JSONObject actionParams = firstObject.getJSONObject("actionParams");
```

(3) Extract the individual string values from the actionParams object

```
String id = actionParams.getString("id");
```

I don't know if this is the whole string but the idea is the same. Create one object and then unwrap step by step to get the others.

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject has a function getJSONObject() as Rarw mentioned.You can find more on [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject%28java.lang.String%29)